# Get start and end times from datetime stamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a CSV file that has time stamps and the information on whether that means start (I) or end(F).
I would like to calculate the duration between the start and end times.

I'm trying to load it to pandas, groupby the reference, 'acao' (which states wether it's a start or end stamp), unstack it and then use a fillna() to be able to get a table from which I can calculate the duration.

code I am using:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['time_stamp'])
y = data.sort_values(['referencia','time_stamp'])
        y = y.set_index(['referencia','acao'], append=True).time_stamp.unstack('acao')
        y = y[['I','F']]
```

The expected result is the following (I hope I was able to format the tables correctly):

```
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| referencia |             I              |             F              |
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|        111 | 2019-10-23 23:26:18.325750 |                            |
|        111 |                            | 2019-10-23 23:42:45.719985 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:38:10.434322 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:38:19.986666 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:39:08.760218 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:39:42.762875 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:40:02.301749 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:40:24.000795 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 23:24:59.687386 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:48:07.831072 |
|        133 | 2019-10-23 22:42:14.712779 |                            |
|        133 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:42:20.159414 |
|        156 | 2019-10-26 11:47:13.848750 |                            |
|        156 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:47:21.289268 |
|        199 | 2019-10-23 22:44:30.502311 |                            |
|        199 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:44:38.154283 |
|        555 | 2019-10-23 23:34:35.322073 |                            |
|        555 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:48:13.330636 |
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

But unfortunately, all I can get is:

```
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| referencia |             I              |             F              |
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:38:10.434322 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:38:19.986666 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:39:08.760218 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:39:42.762875 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 22:40:02.301749 |                            |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:40:24.000795 |
|        133 | 2019-10-23 22:42:14.712779 |                            |
|        133 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:42:20.159414 |
|        199 | 2019-10-23 22:44:30.502311 |                            |
|        199 |                            | 2019-10-23 22:44:38.154283 |
|        123 | 2019-10-23 23:24:59.687386 |                            |
|        111 | 2019-10-23 23:26:18.325750 |                            |
|        555 | 2019-10-23 23:34:35.322073 |                            |
|        111 |                            | 2019-10-23 23:42:45.719985 |
|        156 | 2019-10-26 11:47:13.848750 |                            |
|        156 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:47:21.289268 |
|        123 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:48:07.831072 |
|        555 |                            | 2019-10-26 11:48:13.330636 |
+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I cannot groupby because it gives me the following error when I try it:
"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

I forgot to attach the source data, it is not below:

```
utilizador,referencia,time_stamp,acao
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:38:10.434322,I
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:38:19.986666,F
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:39:08.760218,I
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:39:42.762875,F
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:40:02.301749,I
AG,123,2019-10-23 22:40:24.000795,F
AG,133,2019-10-23 22:42:14.712779,I
AG,133,2019-10-23 22:42:20.159414,F
AG,199,2019-10-23 22:44:30.502311,I
AG,199,2019-10-23 22:44:38.154283,F
AG,123,2019-10-23 23:24:59.687386,I
AG,111,2019-10-23 23:26:18.325750,I
AG,555,2019-10-23 23:34:35.322073,I
AG,111,2019-10-23 23:42:45.719985,F
AA,156,2019-10-26 11:47:13.848750,I
AG,156,2019-10-26 11:47:21.289268,F
AG,123,2019-10-26 11:48:07.831072,F
AG,555,2019-10-26 11:48:13.330636,F
```

Comment: You should show also the input. The subsample of your csv which should lead to the expected result. It is nearly impossible to help you without that.

Comment: @Valentino you are right, I intended to paste the source data but was so worried about the formatting of the tables that I ended up forgetting to paste it. Edited the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that:

- both *I* and *F* columns are of *datetime* type,
- *referencia* is a "normal" column (not index).

In order to keep the printout in a reasonable horizontal size,
I dropped fractional parts of seconds from your data, so my results
are a bit different from yours.

Start from moving data in *F* column 1 cell up:

```
df.F = df.F.shift(-1)
```

Then drop rows with *NaT*:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
    referencia                   I                   F
0          111 2019-10-23 23:26:18 2019-10-23 23:42:45
2          123 2019-10-23 22:38:10 2019-10-23 22:38:19
4          123 2019-10-23 22:39:08 2019-10-23 22:39:42
6          123 2019-10-23 22:40:02 2019-10-23 22:40:24
8          123 2019-10-23 23:24:59 2019-10-26 11:48:07
10         133 2019-10-23 22:42:14 2019-10-23 22:42:20
12         156 2019-10-26 11:47:13 2019-10-26 11:47:21
14         199 2019-10-23 22:44:30 2019-10-23 22:44:38
16         555 2019-10-23 23:34:35 2019-10-26 11:48:13
```

Then, having both time values in the same row, to compute the *duration* column, run:

```
df['duration'] = df.F - df.I
```

For my source data, the result is:

```
    referencia                   I                   F        duration
0          111 2019-10-23 23:26:18 2019-10-23 23:42:45 0 days 00:16:27
2          123 2019-10-23 22:38:10 2019-10-23 22:38:19 0 days 00:00:09
4          123 2019-10-23 22:39:08 2019-10-23 22:39:42 0 days 00:00:34
6          123 2019-10-23 22:40:02 2019-10-23 22:40:24 0 days 00:00:22
8          123 2019-10-23 23:24:59 2019-10-26 11:48:07 2 days 12:23:08
10         133 2019-10-23 22:42:14 2019-10-23 22:42:20 0 days 00:00:06
12         156 2019-10-26 11:47:13 2019-10-26 11:47:21 0 days 00:00:08
14         199 2019-10-23 22:44:30 2019-10-23 22:44:38 0 days 00:00:08
16         555 2019-10-23 23:34:35 2019-10-26 11:48:13 2 days 12:13:38
```

## Edit following publication of source data

To have *time_stamp* column as "real" timestamp (not a string), pass *parse_dates=[2]* parameter to *read_csv*.

Then, to reformat your DataFrame take the following approach:

Define a reformatting function, which will be applied to each group (consecutive pair of rows):

```
def reformat(grp):
    tStart = grp.iloc[0, 2]
    tEnd = grp.iloc[1, 2]
    return pd.Series(grp.iloc[0, 0:3].tolist() + [tEnd, tEnd - tStart],
        index=['utilizador', 'referencia', 'start', 'end', 'duration'])
```

Then just apply it:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2).apply(reformat)
```

For your source data, with dropped fractional parts of seconds, the result is:

```
  utilizador  referencia               start                 end duration
0         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:38:10 2019-10-23 22:38:19 00:00:09
1         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:39:08 2019-10-23 22:39:42 00:00:34
2         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:40:02 2019-10-23 22:40:24 00:00:22
3         AG         133 2019-10-23 22:42:14 2019-10-23 22:42:20 00:00:06
4         AG         199 2019-10-23 22:44:30 2019-10-23 22:44:38 00:00:08
5         AG         123 2019-10-23 23:24:59 2019-10-23 23:26:18 00:01:19
6         AG         555 2019-10-23 23:34:35 2019-10-23 23:42:45 00:08:10
7         AA         156 2019-10-26 11:47:13 2019-10-26 11:47:21 00:00:08
8         AG         123 2019-10-26 11:48:07 2019-10-26 11:48:13 00:00:06
```

One more remark: I noticed some disorder in your data, e.g. you have
**only one row** for:

- *utilizador == 'AA'*,
- *utilizador == 'AG'* and *referencia == 156*.

To use my scheme:

- the input file should contain consecutive pairs of rows concerning
  the same *utilizador* and *referencia*,
- each pair should have first row for *acao =='I'* and the second
  for *acao =='F'*.

Or at least it should be possible to sort your data to this order.

Or maybe the 2 indicated rows should be for the same *utilizador*
(and they are "in pair with each other")?

## Edit 2

I changed *AG,156* in your data to *AA,156* (to put the previous row and this one in pair).

Then I added sort to your data and then applied *reformat*:

```
df = df.sort_values(['utilizador', 'referencia', 'time_stamp'])\
    .groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2).apply(reformat)
```

For such changed data, the result is:

```
  utilizador  referencia               start                 end        duration
0         AA         156 2019-10-26 11:47:13 2019-10-26 11:47:21 0 days 00:00:08
1         AG         111 2019-10-23 23:26:18 2019-10-23 23:42:45 0 days 00:16:27
2         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:38:10 2019-10-23 22:38:19 0 days 00:00:09
3         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:39:08 2019-10-23 22:39:42 0 days 00:00:34
4         AG         123 2019-10-23 22:40:02 2019-10-23 22:40:24 0 days 00:00:22
5         AG         123 2019-10-23 23:24:59 2019-10-26 11:48:07 2 days 12:23:08
6         AG         133 2019-10-23 22:42:14 2019-10-23 22:42:20 0 days 00:00:06
7         AG         199 2019-10-23 22:44:30 2019-10-23 22:44:38 0 days 00:00:08
8         AG         555 2019-10-23 23:34:35 2019-10-26 11:48:13 2 days 12:13:38
```

what is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you, your answer teached me some new things. Unfortunately, I had forgotten to attach the csv data so my main problem is still unsolved.

Comment: I extended my answer. I hope that now the problem is solved.